# SQL On Duplicate Key Update - On A Non-Primary-Key?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

**EDIT:** Can anyone explain how I would use **MERGE** to solve this? Syntax is REALLY confusing me: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

I have a table called dbo.Customers_DefaultValues where basically if a customer forgets to input a value I will set that value in the database to a default specific to that customer.

[image: The database table]

The key in the table is the Id. The FieldId is not unique to each customer so for example **CustomerId = 1** and **CustomerId = 2** can both have a **FieldId = 11**. What I want to do is that if I add a new value to a FieldId for a customer that already has a value - I want to update that value.

I have read and tried with **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** but it keeps giving me errors.

[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is a mysql native expression, are you doing this in mysql or MS Sql server?

Comment: INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIELDNAME =VALUE(`Value`); So VALUE() takes the Value from the argument between and `Value` is the argument name.

Comment: If you are using only MySQL, remove the sql-server tag from your question.

Comment: @Uporabnik003 in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @DanGuzman I am trying the INSERT in SQL Server Management Studio and then I will use it in my ASP.net code later when I see the syntax is correct.

Comment: @BerndBuffen could you rephrase that? I really don't understand what you wrote, sorry.

Comment: INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a); That means, you insert 2 Rows with the fields a,b, and c and in the first row value 1,2,3 and in the second row 4,5,6. If you have a duplicate key field c was set to the VALUE of the argument for field a . In the first row it is 1 and and the second its 4.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is used for Microsoft SQL server which does not support "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" command, you will have to find another way.

Comment: @Uporabnik003 Well that's a bummer... any suggestions? Anyone?

Comment: Maybe merge could work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server using `MERGE`:

```
MERGE dbo.Customers_DefaultValues AS target
USING (SELECT 4,11, 'Test2') AS source (CustomerId, FieldId, Value)
ON (target.CustomerId = source.CustomerId AND target.FieldId = source.FieldId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET value = source.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (CustomerId, FieldId, Value)
  VALUES source.CustomerId, Source.FieldId, Source.Calue
END;
```

In practice is often better to try to insert and handle the key violation by doing an update, [since MERGE is actually not atomic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/02/25/why-is-tsql-merge-failing-with-a-primary-key-violation-isn-t-it-atomic.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you got any good guides on how to handle key violations instead then I'm all ears. Marked as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I don't have the tables or data, so there could be problems:

**invalid solution edited out, @Remus Rusanu solution is correct.**

Be careful of duplicate rows in table, if there is more than one row for CustomerId and FieldId MERGE will give you errors.

Comment: This MERGE using same table both as source and destination is rather unorthodox.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, the Src table is of no use if I fix the values 4 and 11. Will edit that, your solution works.